# Choose OutputCache policy based on query string

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC application where certain resources are addressed like this:

```
/controller/action/id?revision=123
```

The **revision** parameter is optional:

- if it is missing I do a 302 redirect to the latest revision. I want this redirection response to be cached only for a short while, or not at all.
- if it is present, I want to cache the response for a long time because any given revision of the resource is immutable.

My first attempt was to do something like this:

```
[OutputCache(Duration=10,Location=OutputCacheLocation.Server)]
public Action(string id)
{
    long lastRevision = GetLastRevision(id);
    return RedirectToAction("Action", 
        new { Id = id, revision = lastRevision }); 
}

[OutputCache(Duration=int.MaxValue,Location=OutputCacheLocation.Server)]
public Action(string id, long revision)
{
   // ... 
}
```

Unfortunately, the ASP.NET MVC routing doesn't seem to like method overloads. It expects to have a single `Action` method with an optional parameter instead (i.e. `long? revision`), but then I can't specify different caching policies for both cases.

How can I chose a different caching policy based on the presence of the query string here?

Answer (score 2):

You could write a custom method selector:

```
public class RevisionMethodSelectorAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        var revision = controllerContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("revision");
        var hasRevisionParam = methodInfo.GetParameters().Any(p => string.Equals("revision", p.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        if (revision != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(revision.AttemptedValue) && hasRevisionParam)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if ((revision == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(revision.AttemptedValue)) && !hasRevisionParam)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

and then decorate the 2 actions with it:

```
[RevisionMethodSelector]
public ActionResult MyAction(string id)
{
    long lastRevision = GetLastRevision(id);
    return RedirectToAction("MyAction", new { id = id, revision = lastRevision }); 
}

[RevisionMethodSelector]
[OutputCache(Duration = int.MaxValue, Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server, VaryByParam = "revision")]
public ActionResult MyAction(string id, long revision)
{
    ...
}
```

The first action is not cached. It will be picked up if there's no revision parameter in the request and it will simply redirect to the second action. The second action is cached for a very long time, this cache is made to vary according to the revision parameter value (which you didn't have) and will be picked by the custom method selector if a revision parameter is present in the request.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had already solved this problem without realizing it by making use of 302 redirects: apparently **302 responses are not cached** even if you have an `OutputCache` attribute on your controller method!

Therefore both cases can be handled by a single controller method with the `[OutputCache(...)]` attribute specifying what to do for 200 responses.

Though this now begs the question of what to do if you do want to cache a 302...